# C run-time error for a program to sum polynomials

Tags: c, runtime-error

This program is for adding two polynomials and printing the result.

It just stores the multipliers in array and use the index az the power of parameter

It does sum and subtract but when it comes to product it prints

```
0x0 0*x2 0*x3 ...
```

It's for basic C programming class and in three hours I should give it  to master :-(

It gets the multiplier in an array and calculates the result using some functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double a[50], b[50], c[101];
int dega, degb;

SumArray (a, b)
double a[], b[];
{
    extern int dega, degb;
    extern double c[];
    int i, max = (dega < degb ? degb : dega) + 1;

    for(i = 0; i < max; i++)
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

SubtractArray(a, b)
double a[], b[];
{
    extern int dega, degb;
    extern double c[];
    int i, max = (dega < degb ? degb : dega) + 1;
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++)
        c[i]=a[i]-b[i];
}

ProductArray(a, b)
double a[], b[];
{
    extern int dega, degb;
    extern double c[];
    int i,j;
    double tempa, tempb;
    for(i = 0; i < dega + 1; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < degb + 1; j++)
        {
            tempa = a[i];
            tempb = b[j];
            c[i + j] = c[i + j] + (tempa * tempb);
        }
}

int main()
{
    extern int dega, degb;
    extern double a[50], b[50], c[]; //stores the multipliers
    int i, operation;

    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        a[i] = b[i] = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 102; i++)
        c[i] = 0;

    printf("darjeye chand jomleee ha ra vared konid");
    scanf("%d %d", &dega, &degb);
    printf("zarayebe chand jomlee aval ra vaerd konid");

    for(i = 0; i < dega + 1; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    printf("zarayebe chand jomlee dovoom ra vaerd konid");
    for(i = 0; i < degb + 1; i++)
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    printf("amaliyate morede nazartan ra vare konid baraye jame 0, tafrigh 1, zarb 2 ra vared konid");
    scanf("%d", &operation);

    switch(operation)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            SumArray(a,b);
            for (i = 0; i < (dega > degb ? dega : degb) + 1; i++)
            {
                printf(" %d*x", c[i]);
                printf("%d ", i);
            }
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            SubtractArray(a,b);
            for (i = 0; i < (dega > degb ? dega : degb) + 1; i++)
            {
                printf(" %d*x", c[i]);
                printf("%d ", i);
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            ProductArray(a,b);

            for(i = 0; i < (dega + degb + 1); i++)
            {
                printf("\%d*x", c[i]);
                printf("%d ", i);
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
            printf("amaliyate vared shode sahih nabud");
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is some of the hardest to read code I have ever seen.  if you clean it WAY up, I may come back and help, but otherwise no way.

Comment: `scanf("%d",a[i]);` should be `scanf("%d",&a[i]);` and `scanf("%d",b[i]);` should be `scanf("%d",&b[i]);`

Comment: god bless u @RAJ RAJ  and thank u xaxxon but i havent enough time to even read this twice and can some one explain why .because i always (in cPP) sent arrays in functs without using ampersand

Comment: Cleaned up some of your code. That's all I'm going to do though - please learn to use spaces wisely. Readability is the best documentation.

Comment: i know @icedwater this is dirty code would u please give me a tut ,guide or some thing to read about?

Comment: Compare the code you originally wrote with what you can find on, for example, http://www.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/source/source.cgi.

[This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495255/programming-style-guide-for-c) might also help.

Comment: thanks guy do u have a ymessenger id i need ur help about this code really my deadline is almost reached(1 h)

Comment: `scanf("%d", &a[i]);` but `double a[50], b[50], c[101];` scanf format for `double` is "%lf" not "%d".

Comment: tnx boy  c[] was extern is it necessary to mention the size?

Comment: I hope your coding has improved since you wrote this.  The use of non-prototype function definitions would have been an automatic fail had you presented it to me — there is practically no excuse for not using prototypes these days.  The use of global variables is bad, too; you would have lost marks for that.  When you say "but i havent enough time to even read this twice", you are abusing us, and being completely silly.  You must always write code assuming that you're going to read it several times before you've got it debugged (at least until you're good enough that it works first time).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP has admitted that he can't read his own code a second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%d",a[i]);` should be `scanf("%d",&a[i]);` and `scanf("%d",b[i]);` should be `scanf("%d",&b[i]);`

`scanf` requires address of the variable. For an array, say, in your case `double a[50]`, simply writing `a` gives you the starting address of array `a` which will be same as `&a[0]` where `a[0]` is simply the first element, but not the address to the first element. `a[i]` is the element where `&a[i]` is the address to that element. Hope you got it.